# t-sql NOT IN with multiple columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a Microsoft SQL database, where i am trying to insert some data.  I have a unique key on 4 columns and i want to insert data from multiple tables into this table while checking the data to make sure it will not violate the uniqueness of the key.  If i was doing this on a single column, i would do a NOT IN, like so..

```
INSERT TABLE_A (FLD_1)
    SELECT FLD_1
        FROM TBL_B
        INNER JOIN TBL_C
            ON TBL_B.FLD_1 = TBL_C.FLD_1
    WHERE TBL_B.FLD_1 NOT IN
        (
        SELECT TBL_A.FLD_1 FROM TBL_A
        )
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS instead since you have to deal with multiple columns.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

EDIT:

Untested, but roughly it will be this:

```
SELECT FLD_1
FROM TBL_B
INNER JOIN TBL_C  ON TBL_B.FLD_1 = TBL_C.FLD_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT TBL_A.FLD_1 FROM TBL_A INNER JOIN TBL_B ON TBL_B.FLD1 = TBL_A.FLD1
    )
```

For a multi-column check it would be roughly this:

```
SELECT FLD_1, FLD_2, FLD_3, FLD_4)
FROM TBL_B
INNER JOIN TBL_C  ON TBL_B.FLD_1 = TBL_C.FLD_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT TBL_A.FLD_1, TBL_A.FLD_2, TBL_A.FLD_3, TBL_A.FLD_4 
    FROM TBL_A 
    INNER JOIN TBL_B ON TBL_B.FLD1 = TBL_A.FLD1 AND 
                        TBL_B.FLD2 = TBL_A.FLD2 AND 
                        TBL_B.FLD3 = TBL_A.FLD3 AND 
                        TBL_B.FLD4 = TBL_A.FLD4 
    )
```

Comment: So use IF NOT EXISTS in the beginning, or WHERE NOT EXISTS in the WHERE clause?  Could you possibly provide syntax?  It would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Also EXCEPT keyword can be used.

```
SELECT FLD_1, FLD_2, FLD_3, FLD_4)
FROM TBL_B
INNER JOIN TBL_C  ON TBL_B.FLD_1 = TBL_C.FLD_1

EXCEPT

SELECT TBL_A.FLD_1, TBL_A.FLD_2, TBL_A.FLD_3, TBL_A.FLD_4 
FROM TBL_A 
INNER JOIN TBL_B ON TBL_B.FLD1 = TBL_A.FLD1 AND 
                    TBL_B.FLD2 = TBL_A.FLD2 AND 
                    TBL_B.FLD3 = TBL_A.FLD3 AND 
                    TBL_B.FLD4 = TBL_A.FLD4
```