# In SQL Server, what is the best way to create a union query excluding partial duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables that have the same schema.  I want to create a union of all the fields, but I want to exclude duplicates based on the equality of some, but not all of the fields.  What is the best way to achieve this in SQL Server (2008r2)?

[I see this sort of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407031/t-sql-not-in-with-multiple-columns), but is there a better option?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough here for anyone to provide an answer. Show us some sample data and expected outputs.

Comment: Let's say you have two tables:

          A: City, State, Zip, Occupation
          B: City, State, Zip, Occupation

And you want to get the unique set of all cities, state, zip combinations from both tables:

         select city, state, zip from A
         union
         select city, state, zip from B

UNION default behavior is to eliminate duplicate rows.  What do you want to do with the Occupation data?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with the RANK() function, though as @Tim says it will just discard any differences in all fields not used in the partition.  Below, if you have six rows with B and C in common, only one of them will survive regardless of the values in columns A and D:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A, B, C, D,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY B, C ORDER BY B, C) AS MYRANK    
    FROM (
        SELECT A, B, C, D
        FROM TABLE_A
        UNION
        SELECT A, B, C, D
        FROM TABLE_B
    ) T1
WHERE T1.MYRANK = 1
```

Comment: +1. Might want to use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` because rank will return same value if B and C are duplicated.